# How do I give a variable to my blade and save them to a variable?

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel

My problem is a little bit complicated to explain. I'm doing a blog and did something like a topic section. I have a topic table and a thread table. In my thread table is a 'topic' attribute. No I want that if I'm doing a new thread, I also want to save the topic, the user currently is in right now.

My send button with the variable is this:

```
<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [$thread->thema]) }}">
    <div class="btn btn-primary">Thread hinzufügen</div>
</a>
```

My add-route:

```
Route::get('/add/{thread}', 'Test\\TestController@add');
```

My controller function just send's me to the thread creating form.

My creating thread - form :

```
{!! Former::horizontal_open()->action(action('Test\\TestController@store')) !!}
{!! Former::text('thread')->label('Title:')->autofocus() !!}
{!! Former::textarea('content')->label('Content')->rows(10) !!}
{!! Former::large_primary_submit('Add Thread') !!}
{!! Former::close() !!}
```

Well, after I pressed the submit button, the thread get saved, but without the topic! :/

Answer (score 0):

According to the following route:

```
Route::get('/add/{thread}', 'Test\\TestController@add');
```

You'll get the `$thread->thema` inside your `TestController@add` method so your method should be able to recieve that param/variable, for example:

```
public function add($thread)
{
    // Now you may pass the $thread to form and keep the value in a hidden
    // text box, to pass to the for the form, add the $thread using with:
    return view('FormView')->with('thread', $thread);
}
```

In the form, create a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="thread" value="{{ old('thread', $thread) }}" />
```

Or maybe this (if it works, not sure about the former tho):

```
{!! Former::hidden('thread', old('thread', $thread))->label('Title:')->autofocus() !!}
```